# Image rendering outside of the frame?

Tags: java, image, swing, concurrency, jframe

Im working on a game in Java and having an issue (i believe its with the content pane) when rendering. I have a screen class which draws the background and all sprites to an Image. The frame then displays the image using a doubleBuffer. For some odd reason tho the image is rendering off the edge of the frame. You can see in the link below that the image is rendering 3 pixels to the left and 28 pixels above where it should be. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?
![enter image description here][1]

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/41/weirdg.png/

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//graphics
public BufferStrategy buffy;
BufferedImage image;
Screen screen;

public Boolean running = false;
public Boolean playerTurn = false;

public InputManager input;
public Level level;
//JButton b;

public static final int HEIGHT = 452;
public static final int WIDTH = 768;

public Game() {
    super("GridWars");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();
    drawPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    drawPanel.setLayout(null);
    drawPanel.setOpaque(false);
    //drawPanel.setLocation(50,50);

    setContentPane(drawPanel);
    setResizable(false);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    requestFocus();
    createBufferStrategy(2);

    //b = new JButton("this sucks");

    //getContentPane().add(b);
    //b.setBounds(300, 300, 100, 50);


    buffy = getBufferStrategy();
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    input = new InputManager(this);
    level = new Level(WIDTH, HEIGHT, input, this);
}

public void start() {
    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
}
public void setup(){

}
public void run() {
    final double TICKS = 30.0;
    final double UPDATE_INTERVAL_NS = 1000000000 / TICKS;
    double pastUpdateNS = System.nanoTime();

    int updateCount = 0;
    int frameCount = 0;

    final double FRAPS = 60.0; 
    final double RENDER_INTERVAL_NS = 1000000000 / FRAPS;
    double pastRenderNS = System.nanoTime();

    int pastSecondNS = (int) (pastUpdateNS/1000000000);

    while(running) {
        double nowNS = System.nanoTime();

        if(nowNS - pastUpdateNS >= UPDATE_INTERVAL_NS) {
            update();
            pastUpdateNS += UPDATE_INTERVAL_NS;
            updateCount++;
        }

        float interp = Math.min(1.0f, (float) ((nowNS - pastUpdateNS) / UPDATE_INTERVAL_NS) );
        render(interp);
        pastRenderNS += RENDER_INTERVAL_NS;
        frameCount++;

        int thisSecondNS = (int) (pastUpdateNS/1000000000);
        if (thisSecondNS > pastSecondNS) {
            //System.out.println("TICKS: "+updateCount+" | FRAPS: "+frameCount);
            updateCount = 0;
            frameCount = 0;
            pastSecondNS = thisSecondNS;
        }

        while( nowNS - pastRenderNS < RENDER_INTERVAL_NS && nowNS - pastUpdateNS < UPDATE_INTERVAL_NS) {
            try { Thread.sleep(1); } catch(Exception e) {};
            nowNS = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }
}

public void update() {
    input.update();
    level.update();
}

public void render(float interp) {
    level.render(screen, interp);

    image = screen.getImage();
    Graphics g = buffy.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null, null);
    //b.repaint();
    g.dispose();
    buffy.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Where is that print statement? (sorry if I've missed it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0,0` coordinate of `Graphics` object you obtain from `buffy.getDrawGraphics();` is exactly at top left corner of `JFrame` and it is ignoring frame decorations.

1. **UPD** I forgot one obvious option. `JFrame.getInsets()` provides information about decorations. You could simply shift your rendering.
2. You would make frame undecorated (`setUndecorated(true)`) and render/manage window controls yourself.
3. Or, and i think it is easier way, you would forget about direct rendering on `JFrame`, place `Canvas` on it, and use it instead. `Canvas` also contains `createBufferStrategy` method, so you need few simple changes.

   ```
   JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();
   drawPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
   canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
   drawPanel.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   // some code skipped

   canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true); //important
   canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);

   buffy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
   ```

I've created simple [demo](http://pastebin.com/aG3dTntm) with similar render few days ago for another answer. Maybe it will helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I was previously using a canvas but was not able to use JButtons while using the canvas. I checked around on forums for information on that issue and was told that it just wouldnt work so I switched to this. it fixed the button issue but then the current issue began to occur. Im getting an issue when using setUndecorated "The frame is displayable."

Comment: `setUndecorated` must be called prior to `setVisible(true)`. There is a lot of problems when mixing lightweight components (like `JButtons`) with heavyweight `Canvas`. It always renders over buttons. Maybe it worth to use `java.awt.Button` instead. Or even implement own simple rendered buttons. Using standard components requires additional work, because they intended for passive rendering from EDT and we've disabled repaint events with `setIgnoreRepaint(true)`.

Comment: hmmm...im really not sure what to do. My game uses the mouse which bases actions on points clicked within the frame so If I shift the render using insets then my input is off.

Comment: Yes, I have been considering going back to the canvas and rendering my own buttons

Comment: Thanks again for all of the information. I'm new to Java and you've been really helpful. I'll get this working somehow and it'll be a bit easier knowing everything you've said

Comment: Why use AWT's Canvas with Swing? Why not instead use a JPanel or JComponent?

Comment: Novices often take example from some gamedev tutorial as starting point. Such tutorials are usually performance-oriented and `BufferStrategy` acts important role as it allows to use page-flipping. Even if page-flipping is simulated trough blitting, it is noticeable faster than double-buffered rendering with use of off-screen image. ...

Comment: ... Honestly, I always take that as "best practice", but after your question I thought "Really, why not?". I've slightly changed fps-counting example to use JPanel instead Canvas, and it runs at ~700 fps. Unmodified demo with canvas floats around 3000 (three thousand) fps. Sure, it is not always make sense, and using JPanel or JComponent is reasonable.